# How to make host and guest operating systems see each other

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

I have two Windows 7 and one Windows XP guest systems running on a Windows 7 host with Virtual PC 2007. I also have a laptop in the system.

- All of them can connect to the internet.
- The laptop can only see the host computer.
- The host can see the host itself and the laptop, but none of the virtual machines.
- The host can ping and tracert i.e. google.com and get all the steps.
- The guests can see themselves, but not each other, the host or the laptop.
- The guests only get a long sequence of "Request timed out" when trying to tracert i.e. google.com, and they can not ping each other or the gateway (the host).

How can I make the guest systems part of the network? At least so that I can talk to the guests from the host and vice versa. For example I would like to run an SQL Server on one of the virtual machines and access it from the host system. Would also be nice if I could get the Win7 guests to be part of the same Homegroup as the host.

Comment: how's your virtual networking setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose your virtual machines to the outside world, you will need to enable Bridged Networking in your VPC configuration for each VM. At the moment it sounds like it is NAT'd, which will mean that they can only see the host.

Bridged Networking will make your VM's appear on the network as a whole new machine, with an IP address, NetBIOS resolution, dns entry, the works.

Just don't forget that in Vista and Windows 7 you have to enable Network Discovery manually in order for them to show up as well.

Comment: How do I set up Bridged Networking? When I open up the Virtual PC Settings of one of the guests and go to Networking, I can select Not Connected, Shared Networking (NAT), D-Link -- (my wireless adapter), and Realtek -- (Wired network card, not connected).

Comment: Choose the D-Link card (if that's the one you have connected to the internet.  Bridged networking allows the VMs to share your network connection, obtaining an IP on the same subnet and being a part of the network in the same way your host machine is, rather than behind NAT.

Comment: I left out a parenthesis after "internet"

Comment: Wow, you beat me to it. Exactly what Justin said. Sorry I'm used to the VMWare terminology, but it's the same thing.

Comment: Ah, so my host will still be able to use the wireless even if I set the guest to use it?

Comment: Cause that is not the case if I for example tell the guest to attach a usb drive. The usb drive then disappears from the host.

Comment: Ahhh, quite different. Your networking will be happily shared between all of them. THe connection of your USB drive is a different type of access (I won't go into the details) - so go ahead and it'll work just fine.